# Munchkin Booty: is there a time limit for "Not so fast me bucko"

Tags: munchkin

Is there a time limit in which the Not so fast me bucko card must be played.

The card text reads as follows:

> play this card Immediately after a card is drawn or played.

I drew into a low level monster which if i had beaten it would have won me the game, the other two players i was playing with discussed between themselves and worked out if they could play enough bonuses to stop me winning.

After discovering they didn't have enough between them one of them played "Not so fast me bucko" to prevent me from drawing the monster.

My argument was that the card states it must be played immediately where as they spent over a minute working out what they could have done.

Their argument was that immediately just meant before another card is played.

Comment: With pretty much any card game I'm familiar with, such a wording would mean that it is played before any other action takes place, not anything to do with actual time. You should be able to say "wait a minute" to let the other player know that you are considering doing something before they do anything else.

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to find anything about the definition of immediately in the [official FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/). But my interpretation would be that as long as no other actions were taken between the drawing of monster and the playing of the card, that would still count as immediate.

But as the rules themselves say

> Any disputes should be settled by loud arguments, with the owner of the game having the final word.

Answer (score 1):

The game has no comprehensive rules, as it isn't meant to be a competitive game.

In this case, I would allow them to play it at any time, as they can always 'forget' they had it in their hand otherwise... but really it comes down to how you want to play it.

Comment: Munchkin does have an official tournament ruleset http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/tournament/